Setting the background black in GLMakie (Julia)
I'm attempting to create scatter plots of some strange attractors in Julia using GLMakie. I could not find a way of setting the entire background (everything except the points) black. Here is part of my code:
fig = Figure(size=(1500, 1500), backgroundcolor = RGBAf(0, 0, 0, 1))
fig_grid = CartesianIndices((1, 1))
cmap = to_colormap(:BuPu_9)
cmap[1] = RGBAf(1, 1, 1, 1) 

let
    n_points = 10^6
    for (i, arg) in enumerate(cargs)
        global points = trajectory(Juan, arg...; n=n_points)
        r, c = Tuple(fig_grid[i])
        ax, plot = datashader(fig[r, c], points;
            colormap=cmap,
            async=false,
            axis=(; type=Axis, title=join(string.(arg), ", ")))

        ax.backgroundcolor = RGBAf(0, 0, 0, 1)
        plot.backgroundcolor = RGBAf(0, 0, 0, 1)
        hidedecorations!(ax)
        hidespines!(ax)
    end
end
rowgap!(fig.layout,5)
colgap!(fig.layout,1)
display(fig)

I tried setting the figure background color black and the axis background color black, yet when displayed, only the border of the image has a black background color. Sorry for such a simple question, as I am new to the language. Thanks in advance!

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Consider including an image, to make it easier for people to understand what you want to achieve without running your code.

Your code does not define several items, such as cargs, so I cannot run it.
In general, though, you should set your axis before you plot, so that the plot is done as a modification of the axis, for example with scatter! rather than scatter. For example:
using GLMakie

fig = Figure(size=(1500, 1500), backgroundcolor = RGBAf(0, 0, 0, 1))
fig_grid = CartesianIndices((1, 1))
cmap = to_colormap(:BuPu_9)
cmap[1] = RGBAf(1, 1, 1, 1) 

ax = Axis(fig[1, 1])
plt = scatter!(ax, 1:20, 5:24)
ax.backgroundcolor = "black"
display(fig)

This does color the plot background, via setting the named attribute within the Axis.
Alternatively, you could use a color scheme with a black background, as in colormap=:fire, if you want the datashader function you use to set your axis automatically.
